# Switch screen orientation in Android

Tags: android, switch-statement, landscape, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I have created two layout files for my android application, to manage the switch from landscape to portrait and from portrait to landscape. One in the dir res/layout and one (landscape file) in res/layout-land. But my application, when I try to run it, doesn't see the landscape xml file. How can I fix? Have I forgotten something?

Comment: Are you sure you placed DIFFERENT xml files in each folder?

Comment: Have you set your activity to handle orientation configuration changes in your manifest? If so, don't.

Comment: Make sure the naming is the same

Comment: Yes, the error is the setting onConfigChange = orientation. Thanks of all.

Answer (score 0):

you should try one in `res/layout-port` and one in `res/layout-land`